# State error was called without a registered event handler

Tags: flutter, mobile-development, flutter-bloc

This is the code for the event file

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

abstract class AuthEvent {}

class InitEvent extends AuthEvent {}

class SubmitEvent extends AuthEvent {
  final String email;
  final String password;
  SubmitEvent({@required this.email, @required this.password});
}
```

This is how the InitEvent was called...

```
    import 'auth_event.dart';
import 'auth_state.dart';

class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthStates> {
  AuthBloc() : super(WaitingAuth());

  Stream<AuthStates> mapEventToState(AuthEvent event) async* {
    yield WaitingAuth();
    switch (event.runtimeType) {
      case InitEvent:
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        bool login = prefs.getBool('login');
        if (login == null || !login) {
          prefs.clear();
          yield Initialization();
          break;
        } else {
          String token = prefs.getString('token');
          String tokenJWT = prefs.getString('tokenJWT');
          if (token == null ||
              tokenJWT == null ||
              token.isEmpty ||
              tokenJWT.isEmpty) {
            yield Initialization();
          } else {
            setToken(token);
            setJWTToken(tokenJWT);
            final response = await Api.getAccount();
            if (response is Account) {
              final sensorResponse = await Api.getDevices();
              if (sensorResponse is List<Sensor>) {
                yield SuccessAuth(account: response, sensors: sensorResponse);
              } else {
                yield SuccessAuth(account: response, sensors: []);
              }
            } else {
              yield Initialization();
            }
          }
        }
        break;
      case SubmitEvent:
```

Login screen snippet for InitEvent

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    _authBloc = AuthBloc();
    _authBloc.add(InitEvent());
    _passwordFocusNode = FocusNode();
    _emailController = TextEditingController();
    _passController = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Then in the login screen, InitEvent was called but there is the error of unregistered handler. I don't know what it means. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace of the error and the related code, if it's still not provided here?

Comment: In bloc v7.2.0, mapEventToState was deprecated in favor of on. mapEventToState will be removed in bloc v8.0.0.

What version of flutter bloc are you using? If you are on the new version you need to register the events using `on<Event>(_eventHandler)`

Comment: I am using Flutter bloc 8.0.1. How do I register it using `on<Event>(_eventHandler)` without affecting the SharedPrefrences code?